# $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4y=t\sin(2t)$'s particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Finding the particular solution of : $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4y=t\sin(2t)$

Hey everyone! My professor recently went over this problem and I can't seem to find where he derived a particular equation. Hopefully, someone can help me out with that equation. I shall indicate when I explain below:

We have:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4y=t\sin(2t)$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4y=te^{2it}$$

Next,

$$ a=1, b=0, c=4, \alpha=2i$$

Set $y=e^{2it} v$

> Now my professor said this:
>
> $$ v''+4iv'=t$$
>
> and I have no idea where he obtained that from. I shall show the rest
>   of the problem.

Guess=polynomial and since there is no v term, the highest power is 2.

$$v=a_1t+a_2t^2$$
$$v'=a_1+2a_2t$$
$$v''=2a_2$$

Plugging back into $ v''+4iv'=t$, we have:

$$ 2a_2+4ia_1+8ia_2t=t$$

Equating:

$$ 8ia_2=1 \rightarrow a_2=\frac{-i}{8}$$

$$ 2_a2+4ia_1=0 \rightarrow a_1=\frac{1}{16}$$

Plugging back into v(t):
$$v(t)=\frac{1}{16}t-\frac{i}{8}t^2$$

Putting it all together:

$$y=e^{2it}[\frac{1}{16}t-\frac{i}{8}t^2]$$
$$y=[\cos(2t)+i\sin(2t)][\frac{1}{16}t-\frac{i}{8}t^2]$$

Take note how the original problem says $\sin(2t)$, therefore our answer is the imaginary part which means the particular solution is:

$$\psi(t)=\frac{t}{16}\sin(2t)-\frac{t^2}{8}\cos(2t)$$

I hope someone can help me find the part above. My professor mention there is two ways of solving this problem and normally I use another way but when I realize my professor's solution is much shorter, I wanted to learn his way but I'm just stuck with the part above.

Comment: With $v = e^{2it}y$, then $v' = 2i v + e^{2it}y'$ and $v'' = ...$. Rewrite $y'' + y$ in terms of $v, v', v''$.

Comment: All he did was to extract the imaginary part of the solution , the one with $i$ , since the original problem only required that. We constructed the real part of the complex number $e^{2it}$ ourself and it's not at all required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, simply derive $y'$ and $y''$ from $y=e^{2it} v$ and plug in the above equation and then equate the coefficient of $e^{2it} $ in both sides. Note that $v$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

firstly we should find the complementary solution
$$y''+4y=0$$
$$m^2+4=0$$
$$m=\pm i$$
$$y_c=C1\cos(2t)+C_2\sin(2t)$$

the particular solution is
$$y_p=(At+B)\cos(2t)+(Ct+D)\sin(2t)$$
when we compare this solution with complementary solution, we will find that 
there is similarity in two solution, so the particular solution should be
$$y_p=(At^2+Bt)\cos(2t)+(Ct^2+Dt)\sin(2t)$$
then you can find the coefficients $A,B,C,D$